# Receiving data on non-blocking queue from – NSURLConnection::initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I have a code I inherited that uses `NSURLConnection` with `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:`, and thus receives response data with the app delegate. It seems that the method works asynchronously, but within the main thread, because my UI gets blocked.

So my question is can I get the response to be executed on non-blocking queue, but keep using `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Pass `NO` for the `startImmediately:` argument.
2. Create an `NSOperationQueue` and call `setDelegateQueue:` on the connection, passing it the queue.
3. Call `start` on the connection manually.

Comment: Yeap, that makes sense. I've looked for some time at the way to create a NON-BLOCKING NSOperationQueue, but I seem to be confused about even if this is possible. I also cannot find a suitable/clear sample of such a code. Can you help? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by non-blocking. A `NSOperationQueue` that you create won't block the main thread.